# GPU loads are not uniform with 2 graphic cards

Tags: video, directx

My PC(in Win7) sets up with 2 video graphic cards which both are GTX750, and each card connects to 2 monitors. In other words, there are 2 cards and 4 monitors on my PC.

Now I run a program that is to render video uniformly to 4 windows with DirectX9 programming, one window one monitor. The trouble is that the GPU loads and memory usage are obviously not uniform.

How could I render video uniformly with more than one graphic cards? `IDirect3D9` and `IDirect3DDevice9` seem that there are no API to decide which card we want to use.

Here is information tracked by GPU-Z, this is for the higher load card:

[image: higher load]

And this one is for the lower load card:

[image: lower load]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which display adapter to use when you create your IDirect3DDevice9 (first parameter `Adapter`):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313(v=vs.85).aspx

`IDirect3D9` has functions (`GetAdapterCount` and `GetAdapterIdentifier`) which identify how many adapters your system has, and their identifying information. In your case, you application will need to create multiple IDirect3DDevice9s, to utilize the multiple adapters in your system. There is no system to do this automatically (unless your video cards are in an SLI configuration).

Comment: thx, I reviewed `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` but missed this parameter in create function.